# Sample web service for Active Pivot real - update

Tags: .net, real-time, activepivot

We are having a front end UI .Net Application project(most probably like Active Pivot Live UI). In .Net Application project, other than Active Pivot connection string, nothing is used from Active Pivot Side.

In this .Net Application project, Query Generation(by our own method), call for ExecuteCellset()(Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll) method and processing the returned CellSet to render it in desired form to UI is taking place in class library (dll). We can make connection with AP Server and can get cellset and render it in desired form to Front end UI.

Now we wants to update the rendered UI(for example Grid populated with cellset values) in “REAL-TIME” as in Active Pivot Live and Excel. Please help us to update the front end .Net UI in real-time.

Please provide a Sample project with example Web Service to achieve real-time update to .Net UI like in this video clipping,

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=bDc-WzHnlTk

Answer (score 0):

OLAP standards like XMLA and OLEDB over which the ADOMD.NET library operates do not support real-time updates.

Multidimensional continuous queries and associated real-time events are a unique feature of ActivePivot, exposed with a proprietary API called the ActivePivot Streaming API.

A client with support for real-time OLAP queries should be built against that API, this is a large task that goes beyond that a stack overflow question, you should read the documentation of the ActivePivot product and probably liaise with Quartet FS professional services.